# python: How to interpret indexing of slicing

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
a = [0, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
a[1:4][1] = 666
print(a)
```

The output is [0, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55]

So list a is not updated, then what is the effect of that assignment?

[UPDATE]
Thanks @Amadan for explanation, it makes sense. But I am still puzzled, the following slicing directly updates the list:

```
a[1:4] = [111, 222, 333]
```

Intuitively I expect a[1:4][1] still operates on the list, but it is not.

Is my intuition wrong?

Comment: when you slice, it creates a new copy of the list, and it doesn't original list. 

try b = a[1:4], and b[1] = 666 and print(b)

Answer (score 2):

`a[1:4]` creates a new list, whose elements are `[11, 22, 33]`. Then you replace its #1 element with `666`, which results in a list `[11, 666, 33]`. Then, because this list is not referred to by any variable, it is forgotten and garbage collected.

Note that the result is very different if you have a numpy array instead of the list, since slicing of a numpy array creates a view, not a new array, if at all possible:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 11, 22, 33, 44])
a[1:4][1] = 666
a
# => array([  0,  11, 666,  33,  44])
```

Here, `a[1:4]` is not an independent `[11, 22, 33]`, but a view into the original list, where changing `a[1:4]` actually changes `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution to think off in case you didn't know the position of 22 (and wanted to replace it with 666) or didn't care about removing other items from the list.

```
a = [0, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55]

# make use of enumerate to keep track of when the item is 22 and replace that 
# with the help of indexing count i.e the position at which 22 is and replace it 
# with 666.

for count,item in enumerate(a):
   if item==22:
      a[count]=666
print(a)
```

Output:

```
>>>[0, 11, 666, 33, 44, 55]
```

Hope that helps, cheers!